# How to apply differenct plugins for different product flavors in gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I've two product flavors in my Android project like:

```
productFlavors: {
 flavor1 {
  ...
 }
 flavor2 {
  ...
 }
}
```

I want to apply plugin based on `productFlavors` like this:

```
if (flavor1 Build Variant) {
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
} else {
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
}
```

I tried this:

```
def isFlavor1= getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().toLowerCase().contains('flavor1')

if (isFlavor1) {
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
} else {
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
}
```

But this doesn't solve the problem.

So, how can I apply plugin based on `productFlavors`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Can't you make two modules instead, one library, one application?

Comment: @Henry Yes, I did it in this way for now.

Answer (score -1):

bro u should  `apply(plugin = "com.android.application")` in your productFlavors scope.

for example:

```
productFlavors: {
 flavor1 {
  apply(plugin = "com.android.application")
 }
 flavor2 {
 apply(plugin = "bla bla bla")
 }
}
```

for this case u not need any validation.

Comment: good solution but apply plugin format should be ```apply plugin: 'com.example.pluginId'```